# NPOI method GetFormat("@") is showing "Date" instead of "Text"

Tags: c#, excel, npoi, text-formatting, cell-formatting

I found the solution on stackoverflow for setting one column of Excel file as Text.

```
DataFormat currDataFormat = this.Workbook.CreateDataFormat();
CellStyle textStyle = this.Workbook.CreateCellStyle();
textStyle.DataFormat = currDataFormat.GetFormat("@");
sheet.SetDefaultColumnStyle(0, textStyle);
```

I tried same, while exporting the excel file, it is showing "Date" format for the same column. It is not working for me. I want one column as "Text" format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Question seems duplicate.  please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45330079/c-sharp-npoi-set-cell-style-to-text-string-1-19-is-formatted-as-a-date-disab/45381802#45381802). Actual code fix should be

```
textStyle.DataFormat = currDataFormat.GetFormat("text");
```